# Memory leak identified by valgrind involving use of malloc to return a string that was returned via a std::string

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I've been hitting 'memory problems' in my python (`ctypes`) interface to a c++ library. So I ran my C++/C API tests through valgrind which is suggesting that the following function is a problem:

```
    char *PhysicalEntity_str(PhysicalEntity *physical_entity_ptr, const char *format, const char *base_uri) {
        std::string str = physical_entity_ptr->toTriples().str(format, base_uri);
        char *cstr = (char *) malloc(str.size());
        strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
        return cstr;
    }
```

Specifically, valgrind spits out
[image]

Could anybody explain why and perhaps suggest a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with what a memory leak is?

Comment: You have an off by one error, which is UB and can lead to a memory leak.  `char *cstr = (char *) malloc(str.size());` is only big enough for the characters in the string, and not the null terminator that a c-string needs.

Comment: This is not a memory leak. valgrind is telling you that you're corrupting memory.

Comment: Familiar is a strong word, but I have an idea.

Comment: *Don't* use `malloc` in C++ - just don't.

Comment: Python is written in C, not C++, hence the need to malloc. But that's tangential to the memory corruption here.

Comment: @JesperJuhl In this case, because this is basically working through a C API, manual dynamic memory management is basically required. So, while not using `malloc` is good advice, it isn't helpful without suggesting an alternative.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can it be avoided if the functions I am writing are intended for export via a shared library (i.e. via `extern "C"`)?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Memory corruption aside, who is responsible for calling `free` on that memory?

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems you are correct. I was under the impression that a std::string *was* a null terminated string, which is why I didn't account for it. However, after making your suggested changes the corruption report is gone. Thanks all!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This will have to go to the client - aka my Python wrapper will call another function for freeing the string once its done with. That's the plan at least...

Comment: @CiaranWelsh `std::string` is null terminated, but that null terminator is not considered to be part of it's size. An empty string has a size of 0 and `c_str()` and `data()` return a pointer to a single `'\0'` null character.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh If that freeing function is properly called, then there shouldn't be any obvious memory leaks here. If there is still a memory leak then either that function wasn't called or there is something wrong with it. Though the off-by-one size error in the code shown causes Undefined Behavior which can cause a false positive for any conceivable problem. You might not actually have a memory leak. Fix that error and try again.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for all the helpful explainations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> char *cstr = (char *) malloc(str.size());
> ```

This function allocates memory. If the returned pointed is never deallocated with `free`, then it means that the memory was leaked.

> suggest a workaround?

Deallocate everything that you allocate.

This is easier if you avoid the use of bare owning pointers. Use smart pointers and containers instead.

---

That said, I don't see valgrind mentioning anything about a memory leak in the image. Instead, it says "invalid read of size 1".

> ```
>  strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());
> ```

The behaviour on this line is undefined. This always overflows the allocated buffer. At least `str.size() + 1` must be allocated so that the null terminator fits into the buffer.

---

P.S. Do not use malloc in C++. Use `new` and `new[]` instead. Or if possible, `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::make_unique` etc.

Comment: Providing an alternative to `malloc` would be helpful, like `new[]` or `release`ing a `unique_ptr`. A raw owning pointer is unavoidable here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I doubt that it is unavoidable. But it may be be reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps I have a misunderstanding here - entirely posisble given how new I am to the language, but when using the `extern "C"` command we are saying to the compiler that we are using `C` code, and therefore some aspects of the C++ language (such as `new`, `delete` or smart pointers) are not available. Is this correct?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Only the interface of such function cannot have C++ things (assuming you want to call the function from C). The definition is going to be compiled as C++, so it is not restricted.